# In a JUnit test is there a rule to set the subject of the test

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I've been writing a lot of JUnit tests lately and see this same boilerplate pattern.

```
public class MathOpTest {
   private MathOp a;

   @Before
   public void setUp(){
      a = new MathOp();
   }
   ...
}
```

Is there an annotation to set this up for me as I always need to write a `setUp` method and it usually only has the single class I'm testing.

Something like:

```
public class MathOpTest {
   @TestSubject
   private MathOp a;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the fields when they are declared:

```
public class MathOpTest {
  private final MathOp mathOp = new MathOp();

  ...
}
```

This is simple and straight-forward, so I recommend that you **assign fields in your test class at declaration time** whenever possible (certainly in the case you gave).

If you want to understand a bit more, read on.

- JUnit will create a unique instance of your test class for each test method, so even if your test modifies internal state of `MathOp`, using fields this way is safe as long as your tests don't modify global state.
- For JUnit4-style tests (i.e. tests that do not extend `junit.framework.TestCase`) JUnit will create the test class just before the test method is run, and make it eligible for garbage collection after the test method completes.

**Use `@Before` methods for more complex initialization.**

Usually I use `@Before` when:

- Initialization of the field is complex
- Initialization of the field requires calling code that is declared to throw a checked exception
- You need to do initialization after a `@Rule` has been applied (for instance, injecting a mock into a constructor)

Usually you would create the object under test in the test method when the class needs to be constructed different ways for different use cases.

**Examples**

Here is an example of using `@Before` and `initMocks()`:

```
public class MathOpTest {
  @Mock private Calculator mockCalculator;
  @Mock private Supplier<Double> mockPreviousResultSupplier;
  private MathOp mathOp;

  @Before
  public void createMathOp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mathOp = new MathOp(
        mockCalculator, mockPreviousResultSupplier);
  }

  ...
}
```

Here's an example of a `@Before` method that uses the result of a `@Rule`:

```
public class MyWriterTest {
  @Rule public final TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();
  private File output;
  private MyWriter writer;

  @Before
  public void createMyWriter() {
    output = folder.newFile();
    writer = new MyWriter(output);
  }

  ...
}
```

*Aside:* I personally wouldn't recommend using `@InjectMocks` to create the class you are testing. It's too much magic for my taste. Having an explicit constructor is cleaner and simpler, and I like my tests to be clear and simple :-)

Comment: I did a lot of experiments and found, as you say, that you get a new instance of the Test class for each test rather than, as I previously thought, the same instance being reused. Been too busy to get back here and upload my results so thanks for answering.

Comment: @DavidNewcomb creating a unique instance of the test class for each test was an international design decision of JUnit. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like this directly exists in vanilla JUnit to my recollection.  Most people elect to either initialize their test subject in a `@Before` statement, or inside of their tests.  In its defense, it makes it clear what is being established before the tests are run, and it always resets the state of your test object.

If you're using Mockito, you actually do have the benefits of declaring a class and annotating it with [`@InjectMocks`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) to both instantiate the class and inject whatever `@Mock` classes you had prior.

Comment: The trouble of `InjectMock` and `Mock` is they create mocks and I'd like to create a real instance.

Comment: `@InjectMocks` injects the mocks into a target object which instantiates it with the mocks you had previously declared.  You get a real instance of the test object.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you but.. Yes but I'd like to get a real instance of the real object. I've been hunting around but it looks like I might have to write it myself.

Comment: I don't think you are - `@InjectMocks` *does* give you a real object back.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that `@InjectMocks` will not solve the OP's problem if the class they are testing uses constructor injection to get its dependencies (which many consider to be a good practice, as it allows the fields to be final)

Comment: @NamshubWriter:  Yes, `@InjectMocks` will work just *fine* with constructor injection.  You're just constrained by what the mocking framework has the ability to inject.

Comment: @Makoto not according to [the InjectMocks Javadocs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html). If the docs are wrong, please update your answer to show how to do it.

Comment: @Makoto thanks, but think can stop working, so S.O. strongly recommends that you provide code snippets.